# Ambiguous reference in Stream

Tags: c#

This is the webservice method i have

```
 LoadImageFromDB(int ID, ref Stream streamReturnVal)
```

I have this on the top of the section `using Stream = System.IO.MemoryStream;`

Whenever i consume this method(update web reference) from a web application, i get this error

```
 'Stream' is an ambiguous reference between 'System.IO.Stream' and 'WebReference.Stream'
```

Any thoughts?

In webservice class

```
using Stream = System.IO.MemoryStream;
LoadImageFromDB(int ID, ref Stream streamReturnVal);
```

In web page where above webservice is consumed:

using WebReference;

```
Stream streamReturnVal = null;
streamReturnVal = new MemoryStream();

WebserviceInstanceName.LoadImageFromDB(100,streamReturnVal );
```

PS: Stream  - is from System.IO.Stream

Comment: having a *using Stream = System.IO.MemoryStream;* doesn't help much, unless you remove *using System.IO* as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So this is caused when you have two namespaces that contain Types with the same name within a single piece of code.

So this section

```
using Stream = System.IO.MemoryStream;
LoadImageFromDB(int ID, ref Stream streamReturnVal);
```

should explicitly define what kind of `Stream` is being passed.

It should probably look something like this

```
using Stream = System.IO.MemoryStream;
LoadImageFromDB(int ID, ref System.IO.Stream streamReturnVal);
```

Comment: @msarchet - Thanks, i will let you know after i test.

Comment: @Pauli, that's what I meant, fixing that now

Comment: i know, just wanted to point it out so you could correct it :)

Comment: @msarchet - Thanks, but still i get "Ambiguous reference in Stream" error, any thoughts?

Comment: @Sharpeye500 did you also fix the one in WebRefrence

Comment: @msarchet - Thanks. I was not able to fix this issue, so i converted return type as byte[] & in the front end there is byte to stream conversion, which saved time.

Comment: Hmm, that's odd it's probably something that wasn't visible in the code you showed then, glad it's fixed tho.

Answer (score 0):

Try moving the `using Stream = System.IO.MemoryStream` is inside your namespace declaration.

Comment: I have using Stream = System.IO.MemoryStream this inside my webservices.

Comment: Could you post the relevant parts of your source file? Also, I want to be clear that I mean to move the `using` statement from outside (or above) the namespace where you normally put it, to within it (inside the namespace block).

Answer (score 0):

Do you have using WebReference? That may create a problem.

Comment: @sharpeye500: if your aliasing creates ambiguity, you have little choice - either rename alias or resolve ambiguities with fully qualified class names (include namespaces).

Comment: Please help me to understand by going thro' the code from top section.

Comment: It's not clear what stream must be used in the LoadImageFromDB. If the MemoryStream then: using MStream = System.IO.MemoryStream; LoadImageFromDB(int ID, ref MStream streamReturnVal); Otherwise: LoadImageFromDB(int ID, ref WebReference.Stream streamReturnVal);

Comment: Stream is nothing but reading the image from bytes & sending back in the form of memory stream.

Comment: From your changes to the question, it seems you want to use MemoryStream. In this case, if you declare your method as LoadImageFromDB(int ID, ref System.IO.Stream streamReturnVal); you don't need an alias 'Stream': using Stream = System.IO.MemoryStream; If the alias concept is new to you, it's nothing but a shortcut for not using fully qualified class names